# relation between static allocation and limited scope

Tags: c, scope, static

The scope of a `static` function or global variable in C/C++ is limited to it's compilation unit. What I can't find is an explanation as to why.. Why is static allocation limiting the scope of variable and functions? Thanks

Comment: "static allocation" is not the meaning of the `static` keyword in those cases.

Comment: You have a misunderstanding.  When applied at file scope, the `static` keyword indicates static *linkage*, not static storage duration.  (Static duration is always the case for such objects.)  Static linkage says that the identifier is not accessible outside the current translation unit.  Thus, the answer is basically, "because that's what `static` means in that context."

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger, So the static keyword has two different, unrelated meanings? in the context of global variables and functions it's static linkage and in the context of variables in functions it's static storage (am I right?). Is there no connection between static storage and static linkage?

Comment: For too much information have a read of : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: Thank you @RichardCritten. That answered my question "they control two **independent** properties of the name: Its storage duration and its linkage." Though I'm interested as to why they chose one word to control both things.. Why static storage and internal linkage should be so tightly coupled? Maybe that's another Question..

Comment: Also, the scope of *every* declaration is limited to its translation unit.  (Objects don't have scopes, declarations do.)

Comment: @aschepler - you can access non-static functions and variables with extern. You can't access static with extern.. statics are more "encapsulated".

Comment: @Gil-Mor, yes, exactly so: the `static` keyword has two different meanings; which one applies depends on the context in which it appears.  The meanings are not altogether unrelated, however.

Comment: As a modern alternative to `static` for static linkage, look into anonymous namespaces.

Comment: @Gil-Mor Yes, you can add another declaration, with its own scope, that refers to the same object.  This does not increase the scope of either declaration.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Some static declarations differ between them. Please pick the language you ask about.

Comment: @aschepler Well I guess you're right.. How would you put it then? Accessibility?

Comment: "scope" applies to names , and it's different to storage duration and linkage

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a variable or function 'static' instructs compiler to make those symbols invisible to the linker which allows you to control what is accessible from outside the compilation unit.  This can help with unintended name collisions.
This was much more important before classes were available (aka in C) and was inherited for backwards compatibility in C++.

Comment: C++ is **not** backwards compatible to C since more than 20 years. One of them is `static` has very different semantics for both languages for certain declarations.